# interleaving arrays for mysql update

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have two arrays, one containing the field names which are imploded into a string called $fields, and one containing the data imploded into $data. 
When data is first entered using the `INSERT` command the query looks like...

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table ($fields) VALUES ($data)")
```

(BTW: all data is sanitised)

My goal is to build a mysql UPDATE statement where the syntax is

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET $field1=$data1, $field2=$data2 ...")
```

and update all fields at once, so I need to combine the two arrays to build the alternating field/data/field/data structure instead of all of the fields followed by all of the data.

My idea is to use `array_combine` or `array_merge` and then `implode` into a string that will then set the function to

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET $imploded-combined-arrays")
```

I recognise that this won't work as the "glue" of the implode statement has two different values depending upon whether it is equating or separating field/data pairs.

How can I step through both arrays and build a string that is appropriate for the `UPDATE` syntax?

Thanks,

Cam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$names = array ('foo', 'bar');
$values = array ('hello', 'world');
$pairs = array ();

foreach ($names as $i => $name)
{
    $value = $values [$i];

//  $name = mysql_real_escape_string ($name);
//  $value = mysql_real_escape_string ($value);

    $pairs [] = "`$name` = '$value'";
}

echo ("UPDATE t SET " . implode (', ', $pairs));
```

For me outputs is:

```
UPDATE t SET `foo` = 'hello', `bar` = 'world'
```

Comment: perfect - just what I needed

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$a = array('key1', 'key2', 'key3');
$b = array('value1', 'value2', 'value3');
$c = array_combine($a, $b);
foreach($c as $key=> $value){
    $result[]=$key."='". $value."'";
}
$updatefields= implode (', ', $result);

echo ("update table set " .$updatefields);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
update table set key1='value1', key2='value2', key3='value3'
```

[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/r3xlPL)